# mysql ERROR 1064 (42000) when restoring mysqldump file

Tags: mysql, debian, mariadb

I created a mysql dump using code below:

> sudo mysqldump --all-databases --user=root --password --master-data -create-options > alldatabase.sql

This is to migrate mysql data to a new mysql server.

Then, I tried to restore using code below:

> sudo mysql -u root -p < backup.sql

but I get error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4171: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '*/' at line 1

I have beat my head against the wall trying to figure this out.  Any suggestions?

Both servers are Debian using 10.1.38-MariaDB-0+deb9u1

Comment: Could you please also post which versions of MySQL/MariaDB you are using for the source and target databases?

Comment: Your error is actually at line 4171 of your backup file. What is the SQL statement being processed at line 4171 of your backup file?

Comment: Somewhere in the back of my mind I think there is a potential problem that can arise when restoring backups using `/* comments */` in stored procedures, functions, events, and/or triggers, while `-- comments` and `# comments` will not trigger the same problem.  You'll want to look *at or near* line 4171 in the sql file to figure out just exactly what's going on there, as @hrunting mentioned.

Comment: Show us the first 2 lines of the dump file.

Answer (score 1):

This error could appear when importing a truncated file. Please make sure that sql file is complete.

When using mysqldump like this there is no error message when disk is full.